# How to display this JSON response in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing learning module in My React native app. So, i have this type of JSON response from firebase.

```
[
    {
        "description": "Desc How Should Companies Get Started in Data Science?",
        "type": "section",
        "title": "How Should Companies Get Started in Data Science?",
        "section": "2",
        "lesson": "3",
        "categoryId": "621KeXergbNg690pECx6"
    },
    {
        "lesson": "2",
        "description": "Desc What is Hadoop?",
        "title": "What is Hadoop?",
        "section": "2",
        "type": "section",
        "categoryId": "A7IC1AliDVnvZECcU5oB"
    },
    {
        "description": "Desc How Big Data is Driving Digital Transformation",
        "lesson": "2",
        "type": "section",
        "title": "How Big Data is Driving Digital Transformation",
        "section": "3",
        "categoryId": "JNK9qIKIKW8gvXvWJ19w"
    },
]
```

and My Design is:

[image]

So how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are we supposed to figure out what all of that random looking data means and how if fits into your UI?

Comment: @crashmstr, This response is inserted in firebase using Admin panel. So i am confuse. How to print in current UI.

Comment: You UI would imply that lessons have the "top" priority and they have "sections'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the response should be structured better but to answer your question you can form an array of lessons that include sections by using this logic

```
 const groupByLesson = (arr) => {
        const array = [];
        return arr.reduce((memo, x) => {
            const lessonIndex = memo.findIndex(
                (obj) => obj?.lessonNumber == x.lesson
            );
            if (lessonIndex == -1) {
                memo.push({ lessonNumber: x.lesson, sections: [x] });
            } else {
                const sortedSections = [...memo[lessonIndex].sections,x]
                .sort((a, b) => a.section > b.section);
                memo[lessonIndex].sections = sortedSections
            }

            return memo;
        }, []);
    }

    const lessonsArray = groupByLesson(response).sort(
        (a, b) => a.lessonNumber > b.lessonNumber
    );
```

then you can use this array inside your function by mapping it to some ui components like this, (made some quick and dirty ui just to show you an example)

```
 const [showSections, setShowSections] = useState();
```

```
{lessonsArray.map((lesson) => (
                <View
                    key={lesson.lessonNumber}
                    style={{ marginBottom: 20, borderWidth: 2, width: "100%" }}
                >
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flexDirection: "row",
                            justifyContent: "space-between",
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>{"Lesson " + lesson.lessonNumber}</Text>
                        <Pressable
                            onPress={() => {
                                setShowSections(lesson.lessonNumber);
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ fontSize:20, marginRight:20}}>{">"}</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                    </View>

                    {showSections == lesson.lessonNumber &&
                        lesson.sections.map((section) => (
                            <>
                                <Text>{"Section " + section.section}</Text>
                                <Text>{section.title}</Text>
                            </>
                        ))}
                </View>
            ))}
```

[image]

Comment: @Roadsar, Thanks, but can you provide full example. So i can better understand.

Comment: I believe this is all the code you need, the rest is just UI customization, please vote for the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Roadsar, Full code

Comment: I don't know how are you getting the response array or how your app structure is so i can't provide you with the full code sadly.
In your app, after you get the response array you just have to pass it to the groupByLesson function, and then inside your component you can add the showSections state, and in your UI return you can add the last part which is mapping the array to UI components.